# ksshaskpass asks for passphrase before kwallet

Tags: ssh, kubuntu, 16.04, kwallet

I have the kubuntu desktop 16.04. I use `kwallet` and `ksshaskpass` to unlock my ssh keys automatically on startup. `kwallet` is password protected too.

My problem is that at system startup `ksshaskpass` asks immediately for the passphrase of the first ssh key in `~/.ssh/autostart-scripts/ssh-add.sh` before `kwallet` asks for its password. The passphrase dialog (of `ksshaskpass`) doesn't contain a "remember password" check box, because `kwallet` isn't ready yet (at least I guess that this is the reason). So I have to enter the passphrase after each restart.

How can I force `ksshaskpass` to wait until `kwallet` is enabled?

My `ssh-add.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh-add $HOME/.ssh/key1 $HOME/.ssh/key2 $HOME/.ssh/key3 $HOME/.ssh/key4 </dev/null
```

EDIT: The passhphrase prompt (of `ksshaskpass`) and the password prompt (of `kwallet`) overlie one another just after startup.